# How to avoid multiple logins from same login credentials in Android Studio Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

How can we avoid users from signing in to an android application using the same login credentials from different devices in Android Studio Firebase?
Just want to know if it is possible to make user login to a single device only at a time using particular login credential?

Comment: try https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#android

Comment: There is nothing built in for this, and it's actually quite a bit more complex than you may initially realize. I'll link some relevant questions/answers.